# How to extend activerecord and tinytds timeout?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sql-server, activerecord, tiny-tds

The symptom is:

> TinyTds::Error: Adaptive Server connection timed out: EXEC some_stored_procedure

It's `execute_procedure` a slow stored procedure on a slow MSSQL Server via ActiveRecord over `tinytds`. If I `EXEC` the stored procedure in SQL Query Analyzer, it takes 29 to 30 to finish.

So I added:

```
timeout = 60
```

in `/etc/freetds.conf` and:

```
read_timeout: 60
write_timeout: 60
```

to `database.yml`.

The same error still shows up. Is there any other configs I missed?

p.s. I did measure *when* the timeout error shows up with a timer after hitting return key, it's about 30 seconds. I have a feeling 30 seconds may not be the default timeout of `freetds` or `activerecord`  and wonders why the error shows up somewhat close the time for the sql to finish ...

Answer (score 5):

It has been pretty long time but someone may need this. I solved this by passing `timeout:` option for creating tiny_tds client depend on [git doc](https://github.com/rails-sqlserver/tiny_tds#tinytdsclient-usage), see the below:

```
client = TinyTds::Client.new username: 'sa', password: 'secret', host: 'mydb.host.net', timeout: 30
```

Comment: I faced same issue and resolved issue using above solution... Thanks